# Executing `import amplify auth` for `Cognito User Pool and Identity Pool` and passing on the `Web Client` as well as the `Native client` fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

Executing `import amplify auth` for `Cognito User Pool and Identity Pool` and passing on the `Web Client` as well as the `Native client` fails with the below Error. Is there something that is missing please let me know. TIA

```
Cannot import Identity Pool without roles.
Error: Cannot import Identity Pool without roles.
    at IdentityPoolService.getIdentityPoolRoles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/aws-utils/IdentityPoolService.ts:88:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at importServiceWalkthrough (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@aws-amplify/amplify-category-auth/src/provider-utils/awscloudformation/import/index.ts:322:74)
    at Object.importResource (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@aws-amplify/amplify-category-auth/src/provider-utils/awscloudformation/import/index.ts:45:42)
    at Object.executeAmplifyCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@aws-amplify/amplify-category-auth/src/index.js:421:3)
    at executePluginModuleCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/execution-manager.ts:178:3)
    at executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/execution-manager.ts:30:5)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/index.ts:205:5)
```

Comment: What's your code?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this issue as well.
The [Amplify Auth import docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/import/#import-an-existing-cognito-user-pool) mention the following:

> Your Identity Pool needs:
>
> - an Authenticated Role with a trust relationship to your Identity Pool
> - an **optional** Unauthenticated Role if you want to use any guest user access for your Amplify categories. (Example: Guest access for your S3 buckets or REST API endpoints)

However, I:

- Using an identity pool with an "authenticated" role with proper trust relationship intact (role, policy, identity pool role attachment).
- Made sure the IAM role I was using to deploy this change had proper permissions to list and read identity pools & roles.

Still no help.

I then enabled "Allow unauthenticated identities" (although I did not want this) and things worked smoothly. This is because this setting will automatically generate two authenticated and unauthenticated roles and attach them for you.

However, as I did not want unauthenticated identity access, I disabled that again. Based off that setting working, I wondered if that Unauthenticated Role was truly **optional**, well it turns out it's not. At least not in the latest Amplify system. Someone must have changed this behaviour without updating the docs.

**Solution:**

> Your Identity Pool needs:
>
> - an Authenticated Role with a trust relationship to your Identity Pool
> - an Unauthenticated Role with a trust relationship to your Identity Pool

To check if your identity pool is set up properly run this function in the AWS CLI:

```
aws cognito-identity get-identity-pool-roles --identity-pool-id "your identity pool id here"
```

You should get something like this:

```
{
   "IdentityPoolId": "your identity pool id here",
   "Roles": {
      "authenticated": "your authenticated role ARN here"
      "unauthenticated": "your authenticated role ARN here"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Creating unauth iam role helped me fix that error.